# How should I update the curve correctly with touchesMoved function?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make a curve like, when user moved their finger, the curve changed its radian, but the code I did was seems something wrong, with many curve when I moved my finger:(
Here was my code below, and followed the terrible build's screenshot. Actually I also want to how to implement this function with UIPanGestureRecognizer.

```
import SpriteKit
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class Home: SKScene {

    var happiness:CGFloat {
        return currentPoint.y
    }

    var currentPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1024)

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }

    func drawhappiness() {
        let pathNew2 = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let startx:CGFloat = 268
        let starty:CGFloat = 1024
        let cp1x:CGFloat = 568
        let cp1y:CGFloat = happiness
        let cp2x:CGFloat = 968
        let cp2y:CGFloat = happiness
        let endx:CGFloat = 1292
        let endy:CGFloat = 1024
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathNew2, nil, startx, starty)
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathNew2, nil, cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, endx, endy)
        let shapeNew2 = SKShapeNode()
        shapeNew2.path = pathNew2
        shapeNew2.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        shapeNew2.lineWidth = 10
        addChild(shapeNew2)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch:AnyObject in touches {
            currentPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        drawhappiness()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a new shape node to the scene each time you move your finger. To fix this, create a single shape with global scope in `Home`, configure the shape in `didMoveToView` (i.e., set line width, color), and update the shape's `path` property in `drawhappiness`.

For example,

```
class Home: SKScene {

    let shapeNew2 = SKShapeNode()
    var currentPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1024)

    var happiness:CGFloat {
        return currentPoint.y
    }

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        shapeNew2.strokeColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        shapeNew2.lineWidth = 10
        addChild(shapeNew2)
    }

    func drawhappiness() {
        let pathNew2 = CGPathCreateMutable()
        let startx:CGFloat = 268
        let starty:CGFloat = 1024
        let cp1x:CGFloat = 568
        let cp1y:CGFloat = happiness
        let cp2x:CGFloat = 968
        let cp2y:CGFloat = happiness
        let endx:CGFloat = 1292
        let endy:CGFloat = 1024
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathNew2, nil, startx, starty)
        CGPathAddCurveToPoint(pathNew2, nil, cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, endx, endy)
        shapeNew2.path = pathNew2
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch:AnyObject in touches {
            currentPoint = touch.locationInNode(self)
        }
    }

    override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {
        drawhappiness()
    }
}
```

Comment: Got it! Clearly example! Thank you！

Comment: BTW, is it easier if I use UIPanGestureRecognizer rather than touchesMoved? I found there isn't addGestureRecognizer method in "class XXX: SKScene" but could be work out in "class XXX: UIView".

Comment: Since gesture recognizers are added to the view instead of the scene, you may need to manually remove them when you transition to a new scene (if they're not needed in the next scene). You can implement the same functionality with  `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded` in Sprite Kit and then transition to a new scene without the extra step of removing gestures from the view.

Comment: Maybe gesture recognizers were implement with touchBegin/Moved/End, many thanks. Hope one day I could help others like what you did:)